# If a nested for-loop has two different starting iterations, is the time complexity still O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If we have a nested for-loop like the one below:

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j=1; j < n; j++){
        // do something       
     }
}
```

Would the worst-case complexity be `O(n^2)` even though `j` (at worst) will always search n-1 of the array/list?

Comment: `n*(n-1)=O(n^2)`

Comment: yeah, n * (n-1) is still O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you both! I was trying to find my old class notes regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only subtracting a constant, so the complexity of the inner loop still grows with n, so that loop is O(n).  Both nested together are O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the `1` being a constant and not really effecting the loop as a whole. Because you said, O(n) * O(n-1) is still O(n^2) + n

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how the iterations are defined. To take your example,

```
n*(n-1) = n^2 - n
```

but complexity analysis defers to the largest exponent since the smaller ones become insignificant as `n` tends to infinity.

However, if you would define a second iteration as:

```
for i = 0 to n:
  for j = (n-1000000) to n:
```

we would have an `O(n * constant)` or `O(n)` complexity.